# test() is not working properly in javascript

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```
$('#filter').on('input', function(event) {
    var options = $('#Id').empty().scrollTop(0).data("options");
    var search = $.trim($('#Id').val());
    var regex = new RegExp(search, 'gi');
    $.each(options,function(key,option){
        console.log(regex.test(option.text));
        if (regex.test(option.text)){
            $('#Id').append("<option value="+option.value+" "+((option.disabled ==1)?'disabled':'')+">"+option.text+"</option>");
        }
    }.bind(this));
}.bind(this));
```

The console returns true for fullstop(".") though option doesn't have fullstop(".").

Comment: `.` in regex means any character.

Comment: what do you want to do in regex. I mean what condition you need to test?

Comment: its like a filter if user type in filter, matched values will be displayed

Comment: regex have the typed string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many characters with special meaning in [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), including `.` which matches any character.

If you want to find literally what's in `search` (but case-insensitive), you might consider not using regular expressions at all, just simple string methods:

```
var lcSearch = search.toLowerCase();
```

and then in the loop

```
if (option.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(lcSearch) !== -1)
```

E.g.:

```
$('#filter').on('input', function(event) {
        var options = $('#Id').empty().scrollTop(0).data("options");
        var search = $.trim($('#Id').val());
        var lcSearch = search.toLowerCase();
         $.each(options,function(key,option){
            if (option.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(lcSearch) !== -1){
                $('#Id').append("<option value="+option.value+" "+((option.disabled ==1)?'disabled':'')+">"+option.text+"</option>");
            }
        }.bind(this));
    }.bind(this));
```